# why errors don't match nil ? Go

Tags: go

Why when you use negatively compare an error with nil if provides the expected output but when you try to compare it using the 'positive' operator it 'doesn't work'? I think the code  See below

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "errors"

func main() {
    err := makeError
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("as expected")

        err = noError
        if err == nil {
            fmt.Println("as expected")
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Why no error ?")
        }
    }
}

func makeError() error {
    return errors.New("error!")
}

func noError() (err error) {
    return
}
```

[Play this thing!](http://play.golang.org/p/vLWd1q2_2g)

Comment: Are you intentionally inserting the function `makeError` into the variable `err`, or is that a mistake? Try with `err := makeError()` and `err = noError()`

Comment: First: Read http://golang.org/doc/faq#nil_error carefully. Second: Fix what Andreas pointed out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example code, `err` is not an error value.  With the following assignment:

```
err := makeError
```

`err` is of type `func() error`.  The `err != nil` succeeds because the `makeError` function is not `nil`.  Similarly, `noError` is also a function and not equal to `nil`.

If you actually call the functions, you should get the results you expected.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you don't call your functions, but assign the function itself to your variables. So the `err` value is always different from `nil`.

Example:

```
func foo() error {
    return nil
}

func bar() error {
    return errors.New("error")
}

// err will be the same as the foo function
// you can then do err()
err := foo

// err will be an error var, nil in this case
// err != nil will return false
err := foo()

// err will be an error var, equivalent to errors.New("error")
err := bar()
```

If you try to create the variable then assign to it, your compiler will yell at you (as expected). Example:

```
func foo() error {
    return nil
}

var err error
err = foo
```

will give you the following compiler error

> cannot use foo (type func() error) as type error in assignment:
>   func() error does not implement error (missing Error method)

In the [playground](http://play.golang.org/p/QaQsGc6vqk)